# Creating a recovery log for a TKinter application

Tags: python, pandas, csv, tkinter, recovery

I'm creating a version 2 of my tkinter application and I need a better solution to my state recovery problem.

Essentially, my application is a map of laboratory equipment, and each tk object is a button that starts a series of timers. I am trying to revamp the way my app logs start and stop times for the equipment. At the moment, each initiation time is appended to a pandas DataFrame along with some other auxiliary information, and the dataframe is written to a CSV text file. When the app is launched, it pulls information from the CSV text file to start timers on equipment that is still active, essentially recovering state. Is there a classier way to go about this?